# logged out in 30 seconds, unless the user select select Continue

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make the user log out in 30 seconds unless the user select Continue

```
void startTimer() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      logOut(); //It will redirect  after 30 seconds
    });
  }

  void logOut() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
        .pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.LOGIN_ROUTE);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

create a global variable in widget class `Timer? _timer`
assign it like

```
_timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      logOut(); //It will redirect  after 30 seconds
    });
```

you can cancel the future like

```
_didUserTapContinue() {
   _timer?.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag that changes state when the continue button is pressed;

```
bool canContinue = false;
void startTimer() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
    if(!canContinue)  logOut(); //It will redirect  after 30 seconds
    });
  }

  void logOut() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
        .pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.LOGIN_ROUTE);
  }
```

Then set the value of canContinue to true when continue button is pressed

Comment: how to add it in onPressed?  onpressd: () {?}